# transferring subversion changes between linux and windows

Tags: windows, linux, svn, tortoisesvn, patch

What is the best way to transfer changes that include new and deleted directories and/or new and deleted (actually moved) files in those directories from a subversion repository on linux to windows?

I do my developments on linux using a subversion repository, but I have to test my changes on windows as well. My windows machine has a tortoisesvn repository which I tried to patch with a svn diff output. This failed miserably since my patch contains a renamed (i.e. deleted and added under a different name) directory, a new directory and the files in there.

Do I do things wrong by just applying the svn diff output as a patch in tortoisesvn? 
For now I think that my best option is to have the windows tree on the same svn version as the linux tree and just copy the entire changed directory over the existing directory. Would that work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have two repos running. Do you need to transfer changes across the repo, or some working copies?

Comment: When you say repository, do you really mean working copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diff and patch utilities don't take into account folder/path changes (file moves, renames, etc) so avoid using them in this case.

Is there some reason that you can't access the Linux repo directly from the windows machine?

If these repos need to stay separate, you can use svnsync to keep then syncronized with each other.  Also, if the two machines are on the same network you might want to look at the 'rsync' Linux utility.